# Vue/AXIOS does not completely download

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, axios

I've switch over from jQuery to Axios becuaseing I'm not using Vue but I still have a problem with writing code to allow the data to finish downloading.  My code is

```
            axios({ method: "GET", "url": "https://r123456xxxxx.azurewebsites.net/api/SitesMembers/500" }).then(result => {
        this.member_names = JSON.parse(result.data);          
        }, error => {
            console.error(error);
        });       
}
```

And this works fine for a small amount of records but if it goes over 100 then it throws errors because it has not finished downloading.  I've search for some answers and came across Promises but that is new to me.  The member_names needs to load after the result has finished. Any help is appreciated .

error:  sorry  I've been working on this all day and getting a little punchy

```
           Left.vue?09b1:307 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected 
           end of JSON input
            at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
           at eval (Left.vue?09b1:307)
```

It seems that it needs to wait for the download to complete

Comment: Which errors exactly? `axios()`  returns a Promise, and the `then` callback only runs after the request has finished. Everything should already work.

Comment: "it throws errors" — What errors?

Comment: try to not use `JSON.parse`

Comment: Then the error is  Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "data". Expected Array, got String with value "

Answer (score 0):

It seems that my problem is with AZURE  my max length is cut at 2,399 characters.  My webconfig is set for 2147483644.  I'll update if I get an answer